# Trying to execute addField with aggregate pipeline and it does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to add a field to the collection (to every data). It returns zero error, however, when I check the database, it does not add any field.

```
app.use('/', (res, req) => {
  mongoose.connection.db.collection('placemodels').aggregate(
    [
      {
        $addFields: {
          type: 'place',
        },
      },
    ],
    (err, e) => {
      console.log(err, 'ahsidufhieuahiu');
      console.log(e);
    }
  );
});
```

Where have I made a mistake?

edit

```
 mongoose.connection.db.collection('placemodels').aggregate(
    [
      {
        $set: {
          type: 'place',
        },
      },
    ],
    (err, e) => {
      console.log(err, 'ahsidufhieuahiu');
      console.log(e);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$addFields` pipeline stage will only add new fields to the documents that were fetched, i.e. it will never actually modify documents in the database.

In other words - it just modifies documents in the output.

If you want to actually add new fields to a document in the database you can use `collection.update(..)` and the `$set`-operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: `
      {
        $set: {
          type: 'place',
        },
   ` I replace to this but still it has no change?

Comment: Show the complete query, please.

Comment: As I said in the answer you need to use `.ùpdate(...)` not `.aggregate()` and then apply `$set`. Read the link I sent you, there are examples.